# django TemplateDoesNotExist exception but template exists

Tags: python, django

I am trying to render a template in django. 
I get this error when i connect to the site:

> django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: path-to-azerty/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)

Here's my project directory structure:

```
azerty/  
__init__.py  
├── settings.py  
├── templates  
│          └── base.html  
├── urls.py  
├── views.py  
└── wsgi.py
```

Here's my code:

```
// ulrs.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from azerty import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]



// settings.py

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]



//views.py

from django.shortcuts import render

def welcome(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'DIRS' setting is for a templates directory in your project directory (the one that contains manage.py).

If you want the templates to be on the inner directory (the one that contains settings.py, then you need to change it to:

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'azerty', 'templates')],
```

Another option that is sometimes used is to add `azerty` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`. Then the app loader will find the directory, and you can use `'DIRS': [],`